# Synchronous Testing with Celery in Flask App

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, flask, celery

I have a Flask-based web API, that uses the Asynchronous Task Manager [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery). I created an API endpoint that simply runs my desired asynchronous task, and then added another endpoint that exposes the status & results of this task.

Integration Testing through this API endpoint works fine & passes, however I would also like to test these functions synchronously using the `task_always_eager` setting in celery. But no matter how I try to set this config setting, the application still runs the tasks asynchronously (I know this by observing the celery logs while the tests are running; celery is still booting up workers and assigning them to this task.

#### I've Tried modifying the config variables mid-test file

```
# TEST STATISTICS API
current_app.config.update(task_always_eager=True)
```

#### As well as in the config.py & **init**.py files

```
<config.py, next to the rest of the working config settings>
task_always_eager = True

<__init__.py, I use the "application factory" pattern>
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL)
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

Yet still, celery continues to run workers on this task. This is a problem for unit testing (can't effectively test the function on it's own bc of the bind=True param), and because tested celery tasks don't show up on our test coverage suite with the coverage.py module. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#### The API

Exposed API Endpoint:

```
@api.route('/stats/<start_time>/<end_time>', methods=['GET'])
def stats_endpoint(start_time, end_time):
    task = async_stats.delay(start_time, end_time)
    return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('api.stats_status', task_id=task.id)}
```

Backend Async API Task:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def async_stats(self, start_time, end_time):
    <do stuff, update task state, do more stuff>
    return
```

Async Task Status/Result Endpoint:

```
@api.route('/stats/status/<task_id>')
def stats_status(task_id):
    task = async_stats.AsyncResult(task_id)
    result = task.result['result']
    status = task.result['status']
    if task.state in ('PENDING', 'STARTED', 'PROGRESS', 'SUCCESS'):
        # task was created, in various stages of completion
        response = jsonify(result)
        response.status_code = status
    <more response handling...>
    return response
```

UPDATE: setting the `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` variable to True during config successfully runs my test scripts synchronously. However trying to do so mid-script with `current_app.config.update` doesn't work, I suspect bc the workers that are running are already configured a certain way by the time the test script runs. Would love some insight on this, if anyone has experience in this field. Having both Unit & Integration tests side by side would require on-demand config changing, but would be ideal

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html warns against using `task_always_eager`, but does provide some examples of testing tasks by mocking out the dangerous bits.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Ya I checked those out, they aren't bad but I never quite saw the purpose of putting in extra effort to mock out the "dangerous" bits, when those are the exact bits I should be testing, yeno?

Comment: It's useful to have a few large tests that exercise a system end-to-end, but they're costlly (time-wise) to run. If I can prove that when I call A, it calls (a mocked) B with the arguments I expect; and then a test of the real B (possibly with a mocked C); I can get nearly as much confidence with tests that run a lot faster.

Comment: I agree, but having at least one end-to-end test that initiates a celery task that calls/initiates subsequent tasks/calls, and checking the end output, is ideal. But in order to do that, `task_always_eager` must be disabled, making it harder to do regular unit tests (since it must be set in the config file, i.e. upon app startup). This brings me back to my original question; is there a way to test bounded tasks as regular synchronous functions?